# Why can't I save pdf files from Safari?

Tags: macos, safari

I know that this is a fairly common problem, but I've never had it before: if a pdf is displayed in a Safari window, clicking the download icon in the overlay in the bottom middle of the window doesn't do anything. I know that a common cause is the presence of an AdobePDFviewer plugin, but it isn't installed and Preview is my default app for reading PDFs. I know that I can do a "Save As," but I'd like to regain this functionality.

I've tried various other remedies, to no avail.

Comment: Try going to the adress bar and press the ALT key together with ENTER key, it should download the url you are at (hopefully the pdf url)

Comment: Do you have any extensions? You might want to disable them all to see if anything is blocking the command from happening, then re-enable them one by one until it stops working again. If that doesn't work, you may have to try to reset Safari to see if there's some kind of preference that's preventing it from working.

Comment: I've already performed a Safari reset (not straightforward in El Capitan). I would like to get the overlay working again. Will check extensions: mine are Evernote Web Clipper, Pocket, Invisible Hand, 1Password, uBlock.

Answer (score 2):

The problem appeared to be that Safari didn't support downloading the PDF from the popup provided by the website (in my case 1Password with its Emergency Kit PDF). Instead I had to use <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> or use the File menu in the Menu Bar to save the PDF.

1Password informed me "That is expected behavior — Safari doesn't fully support downloading the PDF from the popup we provide." One is supposed to press command-S or "File > Save As" when I reached out to them.